# How to register mongoose plugin for all schemas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

What am I missing?  The Mongoose docs say that `mongoose.plugin()` registers a plugin for all schemas.  This is not working.  I CAN register my plugin on EACH schema.

My plugin:

```
module.exports = function (schema, options) {

    schema.set('toObject',{
        transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
            return {
                test: 'It worked!'
            };
        }
    });
};
```

My schema:

```
var testPlugin = require('test-plugin.js');

var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    _id : { type: String, default: $.uuid.init },

    ssn : { type: String, required: true, trim: true },

    first : { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    middle : { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    last : { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
});
personSchema.plugin(testPlugin);

var model = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

The code above works, unfortunately.  However, the following code does not:

```
var personSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    _id : { type: String, default: $.uuid.init },

    ssn : { type: String, required: true, trim: true },

    first : { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    middle : { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    last : { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
});

var model = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

module.exports = model;
```

My test app:

```
var testPlugin = require('test-plugin.js');
mongoose.plugin(testPlugin);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.db);
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
});
mongoose.connection.once('open', function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    seeds.doSeed(function(err){
        if (err) { return process.exit(1); }

        models.Person.find({}, function(err, people){
            if (err) { throw err; }

            var person = people[0];
            var oPerson = person.toObject();

            console.log(JSON.stringify(oPerson));
        });
    });
});
```

I've tried moving the `mongoose.plugin(testPlugin)` all over the `app.js` file... after the connect, etc... and nothing has worked.

Answer (score 11):

Plugins might not be registered with `mongoose.plugin(myMongoosePlugin)` because mongoose models were created before you are registering plugins globally.

- In case if you have `expressjs` routes:

Make sure that in your `app.js (server.js)` you are registering  mongoose plugins before you are registering/creating `expressjs` routes (which are using mongoose models to communicate with database).

**Example:**

in `app.js`

```
const express = require(express);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const myMongoosePlugin = require('<Mongoose Plugin file path>');

mongoose.plugin(myMongoosePlugin);

let app = express();

//register expressjs routes
require('<Express routes file path>')(app, express.Router());

// or create expressjs routes
app.post('/person', (req, res, next) => {
    //where someMethod is using person mongoose model
    this.someController.someMethod(someArguments)
        .then((user) => {
            res.json(user);
        }).catch((error) => {
            next(error);
        });
});

// ... Some other code ...
mongoose.connect(<databaseConnectionString>);
app.listen(<Port>);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me - still having problem the OP is having.  Mongoose 5.5.5 using mongoose-lean-virtuals 0.4.3

Comment: @steampowered Could you please elaborate?

Comment: For me the problem was one of my models was registering prior to applying the plugin globally.  Apparently this must occur prior to any model registration.  Here is my github issue with more elaboration:  https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8088

Answer (score 1):

Try requiring your model also in your app.js file. Somewhere after `mongoose.plugin(testPlugin)`.

Comment: This was actually my issue as well. I was setting up the plugins asynchronously and mistakenly loaded the model before this setup was finished. The plugin thus never had a chance to apply itself to the model.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but work , you must define your `Schema` in each file and then export that

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... })

module.exports = UserSchema;
```

and then you should implement just one file for setup your models , for example

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// import all of your schemas

const userSchema = require(./user/modelSchema);
const TicketSchema = require(./Ticket/modelSchema);

// ***  implement your (Global Plugin) here ***

mongoose.plugin(myPlugin);

// define and create all of your models

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
const Ticket = mongoose.model('Ticket', TicketSchema);

module.exports = {
userModle: User,
ticketModel: Ticket,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just another view of what @Andrei Surzhan already stated.

The key here is to **Apply the plugins before the Routes**.

I recently got this issue, where the plugin's didn't work on a Global scale but it did when added them individually on the creation of their Schema.

For reference, my project is structured this way.

```js
// server.js file
require('dotenv').config();
const http = require('http');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const myPlugin = require('path-to-my-plugin');

mongoose.plugin(myPlugin);

const app = require('./app');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

// MONGO CONNECTION
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
mongoose.connection.on('open', () => console.log('MongoDB connection ready!'));
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error);

server.listen(PORT, console.log(`Listening on PORT ${PORT}`));
```

```js
// app.js file
const express = require('express');

// Routes
const clientsRouter = require('./routes/clients/clients.router');
const paymentsRouter = require('./routes/payments/payments.router');

const app = express();
// Parse incoming requests with JSON payloads
app.use(express.json());

// Parse incoming requests with Form payloads
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
  })
);

app.use('/clients', clientsRouter);
app.use('/payments', paymentsRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

As you can see at `server.js` we add the plugin before even importing `app.js` this is because when we import `app.js` we will call the routes and the plugin will not be passed.

---

Another way to do it, is adding the plugin on each Schema.

Example

```js
// clients.model.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const myPlugin = require('path-to-my-plugin');

const clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... });
clientSchema.plugin(myPlugin);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);
```